# Angular 2 Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-services

From what I can tell this error has to do with how I `return` data. However I can not find out where I am missing my return statement or maybe that isn't the issue at all... The error happens when I delete something from my front end here is the code for my delete functions as well as my error handling:

**component**

```
    delete(id){
      console.log(id);
       this._dataservice.Delete(id)
        .subscribe((res) => {
          this.myPosts = res;
        });
          var index = this.myPosts.findIndex(x => x.id == id);
          this.myPosts.splice(index, 1);
   }
```

**service**

```
public Delete = (id: string) =>{
       return this._http.delete(this.actionUrl + id)
          .map(res => res.json())
          .catch(this.handleError);
    }    

     private handleError(error: any) {
         if(error != null && error.headers != null){
        var applicationError = error.headers.get('Application-Error');
        var serverError = error.json();
        var modelStateErrors: string = '';

        if (!serverError.type) {
            console.log(serverError);
            for (var key in serverError) {
                if (serverError[key])
                    modelStateErrors += serverError[key] + '\n';
            }
        }

            modelStateErrors = modelStateErrors = '' ? null : modelStateErrors;

            return Observable.throw(applicationError || modelStateErrors || 'Server error');
        }
    }
```

I took a look at the other SO questions with this same issue but none of them seemed to help me fix my issue. thanks for any help.

also here is an image of the error 
[image]

**EDIT**

Also it is worth noting that this error isn't actually breaking my app. It still deletes the Item that I want to delete. Functionality wise everything works but it still throws this error.

Comment: Does any of these questions helps you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37414855/typeerror-cannot-read-property-symbolsymbol-iterator-of-undefined?rq=1 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37414855/typeerror-cannot-read-property-symbolsymbol-iterator-of-undefined?rq=1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36295535/angular2-typeerror-cannot-read-property-symbolsymbol-iterator-of-undefined?rq=1

Comment: I viewed these prior to posting but they didnt help. I dont see where in my code I would need another return statement or where I would I have to reset my array.

Comment: Since the item is being deleted like you want it to, I would say your error points to not resetting your array. Seems like the iterator is trying to read the item that is no longer there or perhaps an out of bounds index. I'm not sure where you would reset your array but this could push you in the right direction. Hope this helps.

Comment: What is it `modelStateErrors = modelStateErrors = '' ? null : modelStateErrors;`? `modelStateErrors` is equal itself? May be it?

Comment: no :\ that didnt work either...

Comment: This is most likely caused by `ngFor` in your template. It's trying to iterate over something that no longer exists...

Comment: is this.myPosts defined initially and is it an array ? it should be

Comment: Yes its defined as `myPosts : Array<PostViewModel>`

Comment: Did  delete request complete successfully?

Comment: yes it completes but throw same error

Answer (score -1):

Well, first of all, you should not delete items from myPosts array outside of this._dataservice.Delete() call. Before this call completes you have no idea if the post was actually deleted by your rest service or not, but you've already deleted it on the client by the moment you know the actual deletion result which may be unsuccessful for a whole bunch of reasons. It is unreliable logic.

Now, to the main point. Since we don't see the actual data exchange in your application (and most of the application as well) the best we can do is to guess. My guess is there's something wrong with this piece of code:

```
this._dataservice.Delete(id)
    .subscribe((res) => {
      this.myPosts = res;
    });
```

Particularly I'd check what's returned to you as `res` parameter or even earlier in your service in http.delete().map() call before calling json() on it. I suspect it receives wrong value or something like that.

Hope this will give you some idea, but again - it's really hard to tell something about your application not seeing it. It's not even clear from the call stack what exactly is failing, I wasn't able to find such a stuff in angular/zone/rxjs sources.